# Codeigniter function controller 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Go extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->view('start_view');
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('menu_view');
        $this->load->view('top_panel_view');
        $this->load->view('domaci_view');
        $this->load->view('world_view');
        $this->load->view('latest_view');
        $this->load->view('end_view');
    }

    public function contest()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->view('start_view');
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('menu_view');
        $this->load->view('end_view');      
    }

}
```

When i try to access localhost/site/go/contest I get a 404. The default controller is "Go". Some of my config values:

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sajt/go';
```

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Whats the problem ???

Comment: Is CodeIgniter installed in a sub directory called site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code

in your .htaccess add you folder name

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'go/index';
```

.htaccess:

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration

In config

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your `base_url` to point to the root of your CI installation (in your case, `localhost/sajt/`. This setting is used to construct links when using the `site_url()` function, it should not be used to define a default controller. The default controller should be defined in `config/routes.php` as follows:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "go";
```

The `index()` method is automatically entered if no method is specified, provided that it exists.

You also want to rewrite *relative* to index.php in your .htaccess file, but you have an absolute path of `/` specified. This is a problem if you have CI installed in a subdirectory. I'd suggest the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /sajt
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

There, I test to see if the requested URI is in fact *not* a file or directory, which eliminates having to specify them one by one, and the `RewriteBase` directive makes sure that the links are rewritten properly.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sajt';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to your `.htaccess` file

please look at the documentation

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: some explanation would help this answer

Answer (score 0):

1º
click menu wamp>apache>httpd.conf **CHANGE**:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

TO

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

2º **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

3º application/conf/**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

4º **URL case sensitive**

```
localhost/SITE/controller = c:\SITE\controller
localhost/site/controller = c:\site\controller
```

5º Test

```
localhost/site/index.php/controller
```

if it works, **go to**: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

try in **config.php**:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = “REQUEST_URI”
```

**Alternartive .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|img|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```